# using fastDDS on 2 computers with ROS Foxy and ROS Humble (Cannot receive topic on host computer)

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, dds, ros-foxy

I am trying to explore the usage of DDS in ROS2. My set up is 2 computers connected to the same network. Slave computer runs ROS2 Foxy and host Computer runs ROS2 Humble.

I couldn't get them to communicate .

I am grateful if someone can help me with my problem or correct what i've done. Please advise.

Steps I've done so far: On Slave Computer:

```
On slave computer i modified my bashrc to add these lines : export ROS_DOMAIN_ID=1
In a terminal i ran fastdds discovery --server-id 0
In another terminal. I ran my talker node.
/chatter is being published checked using ros2 topic list.
```

On Host Computer:

```
On Host computer i modified my bashrc to add these lines :

export ROS_DOMAIN_ID=1

export ROS_DISCOVERY_SERVER=Slave'sIP:11811

I checked ros2 topic list. /chatter is missing.

I tried running my listener node. Nothing was heard.
```

After this, i tried to kill and re-start the ros2 daemon and just repeated the process.

I'm expecting that after the proper setup. host machine can at least view slave machine's topic and can run the listener while subscribing to the topic from host machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Communication between different ROS 2 releases is not guaranteed to work, see
[this previous answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/341372/can-nodes-from-different-ros-2-distributions-communicate-compatibly/).

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much.
Given that info would  writing a FASTDDS subscriber in C++ without ROS2 be a solution? Or would you suggest, I make both machines use ROS2 Foxy or Humble strictly. May I know your thoughts?

Comment: I _assume_ if there would be an easy solution to interoperability between releases, that it would have been implemented. Given there is no such implementation, I conclude that the best option is to use only one release.